# Best python wrapper for "cd -"

Tags: python, bash, chdir

I want to change dirs back in forth in python script. From Bash I would do `cd "bla/bla"` and then `cd -` or pushd `"bla/bla" > /dev/null` and then `popd`.

Python has no wrappers for `pushd`, `popd`, or `-` (which is a Shell variable). Is there a better way than:

```
import os
curr_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('bla/bla')
...
is.chdir(old_dir)
```

OR

```
import path # after pip install https://github.com/jaraco/path.py
with path.Path('bla/bla'):
    ...
```

which includes another not-built-in dependency and is not very obvious, IMO

?

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` are shell functionality. It wouldn't make sense for Python to have wrappers for them; at most, such a wrapper could have a new shell change its working directory and exit, leaving the Python process's working directory unaffected.

Comment: Correct. I don't mean an actual wrapper (though it is what I wrote). What I meant is a `os.chdir()` with memory

Comment: You would have to define your own stack, as Python doesn't have one pre-allocated (like the shell does for use by `pushd` and `popd`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything in `os` that does this:

```py
from os import chdir, getcwd

_stack = []

def pushd(dir):
    global _stack
    _stack.append(getcwd())
    chdir(dir)

def popd():
    chdir(_stack.pop())
```

Given context I would prefer your `with Path(dir):` example in many situations though. You are presumably trying to get away from bash not replicate it :)

Comment: Its doing what I want, but I'm looking for a built in.. :-)